# extract data from txt file using regexp in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I need to extract some info from a txt file which looks like this using regexp:

```
##FileName = disp_20120803_064635_1
#Plane1
x1 = 10008  x2= -9991  x3= -9991
y1 = 137  y2 = 10  y3 = 158
z1= 844  z2= 779  z3 = 700

#Plane2
x1 = -16 x2= 193  x3= 320
y1 = -4472  y2 = -556  y3 = 5143
z1= 3215  z2= -1309  z3 = 370

#Plane3
x1 = -8145  x2= 5387  x3= 8070
y1 = -4808  y2 = 7643  y3 = 3051
z1= 4212  z2= 4120  z3 = -4176


##end
```

> > I want to extract the file name by the following code:

```
buffer  = fileread('test.txt') ; 
pattern = '##FileName\s=\s+(\w+?\d+)';
tokens  = regexp(buffer, pattern, 'tokens');
fileName = [tokens{:}]
```

But the result is just `disp_20120803` which is not the complete file name?

Any help?

Comment: What have you attempted? Where did you get stuck in your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern instead:

```
pattern = '##FileName\s=\s+(\w+)';
```

*Edit:*

I don't know matlab syntax but you can use the following regex to capture the variables name and their values:

```
pattern = '([xyz][123])\s*=\s*(-?\d+)'
```

The variable name is in group 1 and its value in group 2.

Comment: It works :), thank you so much. I just have another question: I also need to extract the values for x1,x2,..... for the computational complexity point of view, Is it better to have several calls of regexp(Here, 9 calls) or just one complex call with all required data? Thanks :) @M42